# Summations in $\tan^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions, trigonometric-sums

Hey all,

I was just wondering if anyone had come across the following identities, valid for $m\in\mathbb{N}$. I've used Abramowitz and Stegun, Maple, Mathematica etc but can't find them anywhere. I can prove these, though they happen 'accidentally' from a method which I am already looking at. Anyway the identities are

$$\sum_{k=1}^m \left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{4m}\right)\right)^2=m(2m-1) \hspace{4mm} \textrm{and} \hspace{4mm} \sum_{k=1}^m \left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi k}{2m+1}\right)\right)^2=m(2m+1)$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^m \left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi(2k-1)}{4m}\right)\right)^4=\frac{1}{3}m(2m-1)(4m^2+2m-3) \hspace{4mm} etc$$

There are other identities for all even powers but I haven't worked them out yet as I thought that there might not be any point if there are known results for these summations. It would be cool if there were lists of such identities, or even a general formula, as this would provide me with many useful references indeed!

Many thanks on Christmas!

Comment: How do you derive these identities?

Comment: seems you confused m and n in the last identity

Comment: Not much of a simplification, but your first sum can be "cut in half": for even $m$, your sum is the same as $$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\left(\tan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4m}(2k-1)\right)+\cot^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4m}(2k-1)\right)\right)$$ ; for odd $m$, add 1.

Comment: (and something similar can be done for the other sums)

Comment: Yes, sorry I fixed that :) The methods which I used to derive these identities are not complicated but they are a little intricate and requires a certain amount of background information. Forgive this lack of information. Would it be easier if I wrote up a proof (probably tomorrow, given I'm supposed to be sociable today) and posted it?

Comment: @ JM - Yes that is a nice alternative to the result :)

Comment: After further massaging of that first sum, you have for even $m$ the (tentative) identity $$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\frac4{1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{m}(2k-1)\right)}=m^2$$ ; for odd $m$, add 1 again to the left hand side. Yes, knowing about the background would be quite lovely.

Comment: You'll find this and a list of further identities here http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/30/3185.pdf

Comment: Thanks to dke's lead, I found this one: http://matrix.skku.ac.kr/sglee/papers/pdf/article990804-7.pdf ; that might have something you can use.

Comment: @dke: thanks for that, I'll read it properly tomorrow

@JM: My method is similar to the one shown in the above link from dke, so I'd suggest reading that to save me typing it :)

Comment: Ah, then you'll *love* that paper I linked to... :)

Comment: See also Example 5.1 of 
http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/38.pdf.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your answers, I'm going to check out the documents which you linked me to :)

Comment: Another possible source is Jolley's book, Summation of Series. 

Answer (score 2):

There is one natural way to study such identities based on discrete Fourier series. You can define functions as a Fourier series with coefficients equal to your summands. Then your sums will be equal to the values of these functions at $0$. For two presented sums you'll get polynomials of 2 and 4 degrees respectively. They are 2 terms of some "good" sequence of polynomials which can be defined recursively. These polynomials will be closely connected with Bernoulli polynomials.
Some similar polynomials (discrete Bernoulli polynomials) are known as Korobov polynomials.

Some related examples are here: [Lemma 2+ formula (6)](http://iam.khv.ru/articles/Ustinov/nth08.pdf) and more symmetrical [Fourier series for $Q_{2n}(x)$ (page 10)](http://iam.khv.ru/articles/Ustinov/nth02.pdf).